# Wifi hotspot from connnection

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering

So, I have 2 samsung galaxy S4s. Dont ask why. One is running CM13 and the other Stock. Since you cannot put a phone into both master and slave mode at the same time, I would like to connect my stock s4 to wifi and use my cm13 s4 as a hotspot that uses that connection. Bluetooth tethering doesn't seem to work, so how would I go about using my stock phones slave-mode wifi to create a hotspot on my other phone?

Both devices are rooted, and the reason for wanting this is I would like to not haul my laptop with me on trips.

Comment: Have you tried fqrouter2 from playstore? It happens to have a Wi-Fi repeating functionality

Comment: @xavier_fakerat It doesn't appear to be compatable with jfltespr.

Comment: Do you have busybox installed? Try again with busybox, if that fails you can try [NetShare-no-root-tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en). There is a Wi-Fi repeating functionality in that is included ( share internet connection with other android devices via WifiDirect) Please provide feedback if it works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to configure two interface in the device. Basically the wifi and the hotspot use the same resource, I did using my data mobile but using wifi you have to look how to configure an access point. With my PC using Windows you can do it but using your device please check if you have this Settings available:

**`Settings > Wifi Setting > Mobile AP`**

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to usb tether from android to android?